# Pipe 'find' command result list to move (mv) command – Terminal (zsh)

Tags: terminal, find, pipe, zsh, mv

## Piping result list to command - ZSH

So I want to call the mv command on a list of filtered **ls** results of a directory:

```
 print -l $(ls) | awk '$1 !~ /^A.*/ {print $0}'
```

Here every filename in my directory *not* starting with a capital "A" is returned...

Now I want the **mv** command to be called upon every one of these in order to move them in a directory ./Strings.

My take was adding **xargs**:

```
...| xargs -0 mv ./Strings
```

But this instead ended up in renaming my "Strings"-directory to a combination of every returned filename separated with  question marks ("?") - an effect of the **-0** null character flag for the **xargs** command I suppose...

Funnily enough, the wiki on the **xargs** command (link to the german site here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xargs/) offers an example-code-snippet to pretty much my question (very similar to my try), but needless to say doesn't solve my problem.

```
find . -uid 1001 -print | xargs -i mv {} /tmp/Klaus/test
```

Here it complains about "xargs: illegal option -- i" when I try that in my context:

```
 find . -regex '^[^A].*' -print | xargs -i mv {} ./Strings
```

## find -exec *cmd* {} +

I have done some research on my question and what usually pops up is "why can't I pipe **find** result to ...". 
 That's why I did not want to leave a suggestion for a solution with the **find** command and **-exec** flag, though that didn't lead to my desired result either, unfortunately...:

```
find . -regex '^[^A].*' -exec mv {} ./Strings +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to just do this:

1. To your `.zshrc` file, add

   ```sh
   setopt extendedglob
   ```

   then restart your shell.
2. This enables you to use the `^` operator:

   ```sh
   mv ^A*(-.) Strings
   ```

- `(-.)` matches plain files or symlinks pointing to plain files. If you don't want the symlinks included, use `(.)` instead.
- See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation for more info on the extended glob syntax.

  > ⚠️ **Note** that extended glob syntax is similar to but *not exactly the same* as regular expression syntax!

Comment: Very good take as it really makes use of the mv command and its being, didn't know you could include a regex just like that... Though, unfortunately, I am yet to become friends with mv, as it always tells me "no matches found" when I type both (1) `mv A*(.) ./Strings` and (2) `mv ./A*(.) ./Strings` – – any ideas? 

Comment: What output do you get from `print ^A*`? What does `setopt` output?

Comment: Only `print A*(.)` works for me, so no regex I suppose... **Setopt** returns _combiningchars, interactive, login, monitor, shinstdin, zle_ – the 'basic' ones I reckon? :)

Comment: No, it's not regex, but a glob expression. The syntax is slightly different. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation

Comment: If `print A*(.)` works for you, then `mv A*(.) Strings` should work, too.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I think I found the problem: For `^A*` to work, you need to add `setopt extendedglob` to your `.zshrc` file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's very much true! Somehow `./Strings` and `Strings` make a change I didn't think of...

Comment: `extendedglob` was the clue! `mv ^[^A].*(.) Strings` works perfectly now – – thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! And don't forget to click the "Accept" button on my answer. :)

Comment: `^[^A].*(.)`, by the way, does _**not**_ mean the same thing in extended glob syntax as it does in regex. `^` in glob syntax always means "not", while `.` is not an operator, but just a literal dot (unless in `(`parentheses`)` at the end of the expression). What you actually mean is probably `^A*(.)` (all plain files not starting with A) or `A*(.)` (all plain files starting with A) in glob syntax.

Answer (score 1):

After some further testing the next day, I have found it was more little imprecisions on my side that caused the errors...

The correct **xargs** pipe should look like:

```
| xargs -I '{}' mv {} ./Strings
```

## Solution A

```
print -l $(ls) | awk '$1 ~ /^[^A].*/ {print}' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ./Strings
```

## Solution B

```
find . -type f -regex './[^A].*' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ./Strings
```

## Solution C*

```
mv ^[^A].*(.) Strings
```

[* see @Marlon Richert's answer]